# Find select option value by text

Tags: javascript

I have the text of a select and need to find the option corresponding value.
I need to go because the select the item you seek is not selected

```
for (var i = 0; i < combo.length; i = i + 1) {
    if (combo.options.text == text){ // if the text value of the combo equals my variable
        var pref = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(pref);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to compare the option in index `i`

```
for (var i = 0; i < combo.options.length; i++) {
    if (combo.options[i].text == text) {
        var pref = combo.options[i].value;
        alert(pref);
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e0myb9m9/)